# VSCode: I deleted the basic git extension mistakenly. How to install it again?

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

I mistakenly deleted the source code control system from VSCode.
I would like to install it again, but I cannot find it on the extensions repo.

If I click on the source control tab, there a sentence that tells me that I don't have any source code control system.

Comment: try runnign the vscode installer again. Maybe this adds the mssing files

Comment: There is no installer for OSx, I just download the file and paste it in the Application folder. I tried it and didn't work.

Comment: Maybe try searching `@builtin` in the extensions and find the Git one (if its present) and see what options you have.

Comment: with the GUI you can't delete `@builtin` extensions, you can disable them, just enable it again

Comment: I found it still installed, but when I open the Source code control panel, it says there is no registered provider for source control.
I then searched in the setting, maybe GIT it was disabled as provider. Found nothing...